# NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

How to map this class?

```
[Serializable]
public class AgentSourceCounter
{
    private int agentId;
    private IDictionary<int, int> sourceCounters;

    protected AgentSourceCounter()
    {
    }

    public AgentSourceCounter(int agentId, Dictionary<int, int> sourceCounters)
    {
        this.agentId = agentId;
        this.sourceCounters = sourceCounters;
    }

    public virtual int AgentId
    {
        get { return agentId; }
        protected set { agentId = value; }
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<int, int> SourceCounters
    {
        get { return sourceCounters; }
        set { sourceCounters = value; }
    }
}
```

To this table:

```
agentId int;
sourceId int;
hitsCounter int;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a .hbm file.

maybe the below link is suitable for you :

[NHibernate Mapping](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx)